# cannot find def apply[T](items : T*) : rx.lang.scala.Observable[T] in Observable in rxjava

Tags: scala, rx-java

For example, `Observable(3, 2, 1)` should be using the method `def apply[T](items : T*) : rx.lang.scala.Observable[T]`, but it does not exist [here](https://github.com/Netflix/RxJava/blob/master/rxjava-core/src/main/java/rx/Observable.java) or [here](https://github.com/Netflix/RxJava/blob/master/language-adaptors/rxjava-scala/src/main/scala/rx/lang/scala/Observable.scala)

Could anyone please help explain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's there. You just have to look at the right version, because it [changed in this commit](https://github.com/Netflix/RxJava/commit/335ec87201b14125d078d9c57e7fd51f658acb75), just 8 days ago.